# $_SESSION не сохраняется после запроса fetch

Tags: javascript, php, сессия, openserver

Есть такой код, который выполняется по запросу через fetch со включенным `credentials: 'include'`

```js
<< ? php
//file core.php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['action'])) $action   = $_POST['action']; 

switch ($action) {
case 'profile':
  if (isset($_SESSION['authorization'])) {
    $action = 'prof';
    echo $action;
  } else {
    $action = 'login';
    echo $action;
  }
  break;
case 'login':
  $emailLogin = $_POST['email'];
  $passLogin = $_POST['epass'];
  $doLogin = new Login($emailLogin, $passLogin);
  try {
    $doLogin - > login();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    // Если true
    echo true;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e - > getMessage();
  }
  break;
    
    

    //file Login.php
class Login extends Connect {
  public

  function login($email, $pass) {
    $conn = parent::conn();

    $userDB = $conn - > query("SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail = '$email'");
    if ($userDB - > num_rows == 1) {
      $hash = $conn - > query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE mail = '$email'");
      $hash = $hash - > fetch_assoc();
      if (password_verify($pass, $hash['password'])) {
        $userId = $conn - > query("SELECT userId FROM users WHERE mail = '$email'");
        $userId = $userId - > fetch_assoc();
        $userName = $conn - > query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE mail = '$email'");
        $userName = $userName - > fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId['userId'];
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName['name'];
        $_SESSION['authorization'] = true;
        return true;
      } else throw new Exception('Неверный пароль');
    } else throw new Exception('Такой пользователь не найден');
  }
}
```

если интересно fetch:

```js
// здесь происходит вход на сайт, создаётся сессия
let loginPost = {
  'action': 'login',
  'email': email,
  'epass': epass
}
let bodyForLogin = new FormData();
for (let variable in loginPost) bodyForLogin.append(variable, loginPost[variable]);

fetch(phpPath, {
  method: 'post',
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include',
  body: bodyForLogin
}).then(response => {
  return response.text();
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}
});

// здесь должно проверятся, есть ли сессия authorization
let profile = {
  'action': 'profile'
}
let bodyProfile = new FormData();
bodyProfile.append('action', profile['action']);

return fetch(phpPath, {
  method: 'post',
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include',
  body: bodyProfile
}).then(response => {
  return response.text();
}).then(res => {
  // но сессия пучему-то пустой массив
  console.log(res);
});
```

При дампе выводится массив с сессией с тремя значениями, как и должно быть.
При следующем запросе (вывести сессии) сессия пустая (тоже с `credentials: 'include'`)

Раньше всё работало хорошо. Вчера установил библиотеку zeroMq, думал, что это из-за неё. Закомментировал в php.ini строчку `extension=php_zmq.dll` Но не помогло

---

> **1.**Попробовал написать composer remove react/zmq не помогло
>
> **2.**Протестировал на другом примере без всего лишнего, там всё работало, значит скорее всего дело не в расширении zmq
>
> *3.*Убирал все сессии из папки, при первом запуске проверяется есть ли у меня сессия авторизации -- тогда создался пустой файл сессии. Потом
>   я создаю сессию -- появляется один файл весом 1кб и с содержимым какое
>   и должно быть. Потом у меня идет два обращения к core.php -- проверка
>   авторизовался ли пользователь -- создаются два других пустых файла.
>   вот скрин ibb.co/wYWm7Tz
>
> **4.**Выводил session_id() в case login и profile - результат разный. В application почему-то всегда одинаковое айди. нашел вопрос
>   ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468530/… там говорится, что в
>   session_id значения будут разные, и это правильная работа.
>
> **5.**И еще там говорится про то, что нужно посмотреть set_cookie в консоли. Я у себя там нашел в path восклицательный знак ibb.co/SK0M7H4
>   ibb.co/fQb4NNz
>
> **6.**Ещё я нашел в network, что у меня оказывается открыто соединение с websocket, хотя его я нигде не мог открыть! Он находится в состояние
>   pedding, возможно. это и мешает. Хотя обращения к core.php у меня
>   завершаются (200) -- скрин https://ibb.co/C8t7ZB8

Если нужно, то вот гитхаб с кодом github.com/Color-Kat

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105715/discussion-on-question-by-color-kat-session-----fetch).

Comment: Куда вы пропали?

Comment: Я нашёл в  папке с сессиями айди файла с нужными данными и написал `session_id('Айди того файла')` Оно заработало, но наверно так не должно быть, ведь сессии не должны все записываться в один и тот же файл

Comment: так получаетс одна сессия на всех - один вышел, вышли все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю в чём проблема, но в хроме не работает. 
Проверил в FireFox - там работает
Проверил в Canary - там работает

В хроме куки включены, на тестовом сайте всё работало.
В чём проблема в хроме вообще не знаю